# mySQL Join, how to get amount of rows from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

Say I have 3 tables:

p, r and l

I want to select how many rows are in each table, and define them as a variable for table name.

```
$sevenQ = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `p` AS p WHERE `added` LIKE '" . $today . "%' union 
SELECT count(*) FROM `r` AS r WHERE `added` LIKE '" . $today . "%' union
SELECT count(*) FROM `l` AS l WHERE `added` LIKE '" . $today . "%'");

$sevenQ['p'] = total amount of rows in p;
$sevenQ['r'] = total amount of rows in r;
$sevenQ['l'] = total amount of rows in l;
```

How would I go about returning the top 3 variables for such query?

Comment: What data type is added?   you really shouldn't do a like on a date.  You're better off truncating the timestamp off the date and comparing dates values w/o timestmaps.  and if you want to alias the counts you can use  `SELECT count(*)  p FROM p.... SELECT count(*) r from R..`

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from tablea where ... union select count(*) from tableb where ... union select count(*) from tablec where ...;
```

You'll get three rows with the number of rows of the three tables. (Tested on mysql 5)

**About your update:**

Your example can't work. The *AS* keyword is also used in a wrong way. You should do something like:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT \"p\" AS name, count(*) AS cnt FROM `p` WHERE `added` LIKE '" . $today . "%' union 
SELECT \"r\" AS name, count(*) AS cnt FROM `r` WHERE `added` LIKE '" . $today . "%' union
SELECT \"l\" AS name, count(*) AS cnt FROM `l` WHERE `added` LIKE '" . $today . "%'");

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){
    $sevenQ[$row['name']] = $row['cnt'];
}
```

(Untested code)

Answer (score 0):

why not use three `select count(*) from tablename?`

Answer (score 0):

You could try (this is untested):

```
select "tablea" as name, count(*) as total from tablea where stuff=1
union "tableb", count(*) from tableb where stuff=1
union "tablec", count(*( from tablec where stuff=1
```

You may need to make a few syntax changes, this machine doesnt have access to mysql to parse it to be sure.

This should give you

```
name  total
tablea  5
tableb 10
tablec  2
```

Comment: Hmm but now thats an entirely different question. You're now asking for a crosstab table. Mysql doesnt directly support cross tab, you would need to do a lot more work to put it in a cross tab table.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, take a read of http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

try this its if you want sum of count of rows of maultiple tables...
replace 'table1',table2,table3 with your table name...
select sum(t.total) from (SELECT count(*) as total  FROM `table1` as a union SELECT count(*) as total  FROM `table2`  as b union SELECT count(*) as total  FROM `table2` as c) as t